# actionscript 3: changing object size after a hitTestObject

Tags: actionscript-3, object, resize, size, hittest

I want to make my players become bigger or smaller in diameter when they eat a good(theBall2) or bad ball(theBadBall) respectively. ive created a hitTestObject function where I tried to make the ball get smaller and bigger but it doesn’t work.

```
          var player1;
          var player2;
          var player3;
          var theBall2;
          var theBadBall;
          player1 = new player(50,384, 1);
          player2 = new player(944,384,2);
          player3 = new player(488,84,3);
          stage.addChild(player1);
          stage.addChild(player2);
          stage.addChild(player3);
          var player.width: player.width * 2; // 1086 syntax error: expecting semicolon before dot.
          var player.height:player.height * 2;// 1086 syntax error: expecting semicolon before dot.

        //this function checks to see if theBall2 has collided with a player
        if(theBall2.hitTestObject(player1) || theBall2.hitTestObject(player2) || theBall2.hitTestObject(player3))
        {
            //removes the ball from the stage
            trace("a player has eaten a ball");
            stage.removeChild(theBall2);
            //adds new ball
            theBall2 = new ball2();
            theBall2.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
            theBall2.y = stage.stageHeight/2;
            stage.addChild( theBall2 );
            //makes player larger
            player.width =  player.width * 4; // do I have to define player1, player2, player3, instead of their class player?
            player.height =  player.height * 4;
        }

        //this function checks to see if theBadBall has collided with a player
        if(theBadBall.hitTestObject(player1) || theBadBall.hitTestObject(player2) || theBadBall.hitTestObject(player3))
        {
            //removes thebadball from the stage
            trace("a player has eaten bad ball");
            stage.removeChild(theBadBall);
            //adds new ball
            theBadBall = new badball();
            theBadBall.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
            theBadBall.y = stage.stageHeight/2;
            stage.addChild(theBadBall);
            //makes player smaller
            player.width =  player.width / 2;
            player.height =  player.height / 2;
        }
```

How do I make it work?

Comment: how is this related to your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547859/actionscript-3-changing-an-object

Comment: Could you please show minimum research effort and at least look up how the syntax of the language works? SO is not a code writing service. Please don't mindlessly copy&paste pieces of code together.

Comment: they are about to different bits of a game im making. sorry but i honestly dont know how to write as3 and ive looked it up heaps, this was my last option. Im doing this for an assignment and its due tomorrow ahah. didnt mean to offend

Comment: @null i dont mean to ask people to write my code for me, i just need help in knowing what ive done wrong

Answer (score 0):

There's no `player` anywhere, so you can't change its height or width.
And these lines are completely wrong: `var player.width: player.width * 2;`.

You have `player1`, `player2` and `player3` and you need to change their sizes. Those are MovieClips?

If so, you could for example:

```
var player:MovieClip;
var goodBallHit:Boolean;
if(theBall2.hitTestObject(player1)){
    player = player1;
    goodBallHit = true;
}else if(theBall2.hitTestObject(player2)){
    player = player2;
    goodBallHit = true;
}else if(theBall2.hitTestObject(player3)){
    player = player3;
    goodBallHit = true;
}

if(goodBallHit){
    stage.removeChild(theBall2);
    theBall2 = new ball2();
    theBall2.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
    theBall2.y = stage.stageHeight/2;
    stage.addChild(theBall2);
    player.width = player.width * 4;
    player.height = player.height * 4;
}
```

So you really need to refer the actual object, player1, ..2 or ..3 at this case.

This is only one way, and there's many others too. I wouldn't recommend using hitTestObject at all, especially with balls, but this might be a good method for you to start with.

Your whole project would need a bit more planning, but I understand it's pretty hard if you don't know the language too well. Just have some patience, SEARCH info from this site & google, and you'll get this done suprisingly fast I'm sure.
(+You really need to continue googling, there must be dozens of similar game sources and tutorials out there)

Comment: OKay thankyou so much for your help! i honestly didnt know this looked so stupid ahaha, ive looked at heaps of tutorials but i never really understood the syntax so they didnt make sense. Ive created a player.as class which the player1, player2 etc movieclips are feeding off. all the code above was written in the main.as. would it be better to do more in the player class?

Comment: main.as is good for it. My example might work straight up if you replace the word `MovieClip` with `player`. Yeah the confusing side of random tutorials is that some of them are written simply straight in the actions panel and some in .as files. Can't tell which way is better for learning the syntax, myself I use both, actions panel usually for small projects.